# How to pass browser event through the custom one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

http://jsfiddle.net/m2dqd236/

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  $(document).trigger('click-anywhere', $.event.fix(event));
}, true);

$(document).on('click-anywhere', function (event, e) {
  console.log('>>> click-anywhere', arguments);
  console.log('target', event.target, e.target);
  console.log('originalEvent', event.originalEvent, e.originalEvent);
}).on('click', function (event) {
  console.log('>>> click', arguments);
  console.log('target', event.target);
  console.log('originalEvent', event.originalEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>
```

When you are clicking a button in the example above, you get output like this:

```
>>> click-anywhere [p.Event, p.Event]
target #document <button>​Click me​</button>​
originalEvent undefined MouseEvent {}
>>> click [p.Event]
target <button>​Click me​</button>​
originalEvent MouseEvent {}
```

How can I make handler of custom event `click-anywhere` getting normal event in the first argument? In current realization the event I want to be in the first argument is passed in the second one.

PS: [Same question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457207/178988)

Comment: don't think you can and what is wrong with the second argument?

Comment: you can't unless you want to use a proxy function, a function that will receive the 2 events and send to next function with the event you want

Comment: What is purpose , expected result of setting _"normal event in the first argument?"_ ?

Comment: @charlietfl, @Saar, @guest271314, all event handlers are getting the event as the first argument. But I can't subscribe capturing phase using jQuery, so I'm subscribing by native js way and trigger custom event using jQuery. It would be logical to pass the event in the first argument, not in the second, as the current first argument is useless and the second one is out of place in comparison to all other browser events. Of course I know that I can meke a proxy for an `on` method, but I think it would be a bad way.

Comment: well that's how jQuery events work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with jQuery but you can do it with native Events.

Instead of using jQuery `trigger` to trigger your custom event use `dispatchEvent`and clone the existing `MouseEvent` (if you don't the browser will throw an exception that the event has already been dispatched)

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  console.log(event);
  event.target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click-anywhere', event));
}, true);

$(document).on('click-anywhere', function (event) {
  console.log('>>> click-anywhere', arguments);
  console.log('target', event.target);
  console.log('originalEvent', event.originalEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Great idea! I need to test it for some corner cases, but seems nice. At the moment, please, tell more about browser support. Is it right that any browser whic can handle capturing click can dispatch event in such mode?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) it is widely supported.

Comment: In fact I need IE8 support. In my real version I was using jQuery subscription for bubbling phase with trigger inside. Do I understand right, that I have to replace it using `fireEvent` on native dom-element instead of `trigger` call?

Comment: By the way, I've checked and I readdy need to call `event.target.dispatchEvent` not `document.dispatchEvent` as the latter case spoils `event.target` property.

Comment: IE8 might have it's own way to clone/create a MouseEvent object, you would just have to add a conditional statement to use the correct syntax for the browser you are running in but in essence you clone the event object and dispatch just as I have done.  I have given you the solution, it's up to you to adapt it for the browser support you require.